# How to provide Python DLL path for Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

We are using Pyinstaller to build our Python application. The builds are automated and run nightly on different windows machines. Not all windows machines have Python and Pyinstaller setup. So, instead of manually setting up each machine for build, we packaged Python2.6 and Pyinstaller-2.1 along with the source code as self-extracting executables using 7-zip. The build script was modified to use the extracted Python and Pyinstaller.

However, Pyinstaller always looks for Python26.dll from C:\Windows\system32 or SYSWOW64. In addition, pyinstaller also looks for pywin32 dlls from system folders. Is there a way to tell Pyinstaller to look for these Dlls elsewhere? I tried using the -r argument and it did not work.

1. Is there a way to specify to pyinstaller from where the dlls should be picked up or can they be bundled with pyinstaller?
2. Any suggestion to setup automated nightly build using Pyinstaller is appreciated? Build script cannot install using msi.

Comment: I'd like to know as well. 2.5 years later.